# How to wrap existing script with infinite loop?

Tags: python, loops, exit

I have script which has many sys.exit() and raw_input() commands.
I'd like to wrap it with infinite loop.
The forever.py is running from windows idle.
Something like code below, but it doesn't work.
On one machine python console windows are blinking (infinite loop starting process python, it seems legit), but i dont have output.
What could I do better?

module to_be_wrap.py:

```
import sys

def main():
    print('start')
    raw_input('any key')
    sys.exit(0)
    print('end')
```

module forever.py:

```
import subprocess as subp
def forever():
    while 1:
        try:
            cmd = ['python', 'to_be_wrap.py']
            print subp.check_output(cmd)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work like expected. Just correct these two things:

1. If you want 'end' to be printed put it before the `sys.exit(0)` statement
2. There is no call for the function `main()` in module to_be_wrap.py. Add the statement `main()` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating something akin to a REPL ( read-eval-print loop ), although your main() method does not seem to do anything useful for now.

[This blog post](http://blog.hackthology.com/writing-an-interactive-repl-in-python) describes a fairly rigorous approach. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/776418) ( part of the aforementioned blog post ) shows the "core" of the REPL, but leaves the implementation of the read and eval logic to you.

Comment: to_be_wraped.py is only minimized version of my script. The real version contains many lines and do a lot of things.
to_be_wrapped.py looks like above because i thought that the sys.exit and raw_input give the most troubles